# вопрос по sqlite(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Вопрос по поводу считывания с помощью `executescrips()`.

Файл `createdb.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category(
    codename varchar(255) primary key,
    name text,
    is_base_expense BOOLEAN,
    aliases text
);


insert into category (codename, name, is_base_expense, aliases)
    values
        ("products", "продукты", true, "еда");
```

Основной файл:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('new_db.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

with open('createdb.sql', 'r') as f:
    cursor.executescript(f.read())


conn.commit()
```

В поле name, aliases попадает строка будто бы со слетевшей кодировкой.

```
      name                aliases
РїСЂРѕРґСѓРєС‚С‹           РµРґР°
```

Comment: что пишет print(sys.stdin.encoding)?

Comment: убедитесь что `createdb.sql` сохранен в кодировке `utf-8`

Comment: @Jack_oS Выдает 'utf-8'

Comment: @MaxU проверил, все сохранено в utf-8